# Can I combine commands and pass variables in a single line without using a CSV file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to change permissions on new user's home directory. What I have written works. However, I want to pass data from the Get-Acl test and modify it without exporting to a CSV file after testing for ACL "Everyone."

This is where I'm headed: IF a user Home has "everyone Full Control" THEN remove it and replace it with user.account ELSE get next Home.

Since my CSV file has "good" data, could I use an If-Then-Else to determine whether to modify ACLs.

MY appoliges as I'm writing this I'm getting ideas on what to try next...

```
Get-Acl -Path $HomeDirectory | where accesstostring -like *everyone*  | Select pschildname | Export-Csv c:\test\acl.csv -Append
```

This works but I think I can do better.

Comment: where is `AccessToString` coming from? that does not exist on my win7ps5.1 setup ...

Answer (score 0):

in the process of writing the question i had an idea to try:
    foreach ($user in $csv1)
    {
    $SAN = $user.PSChildName
    $account = get-aduser -Identity $SAN -Properties *
    $HomeDirectory = "$($newhome)$($Account.SamAccountName)"
    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $HomeDirectory -Filter * 
    if ($Acl.AccessToString -like "*everyone*")

Answer (score 0):

AccessToString is a field under Get-Acl in module Microsoft.PowerShell.Securty

Answer (score 0):

here is my finished script
    Get-Module

```
$import_mods = Read-Host -Prompt 'do you NEED to load modules? "y" or "n" (Y)'
if ($import_mods -ine "n")
{
Import-Module ShareUtils, PowerShellAccessControl, Microsoft.PowerShell.Security
}
$newhome = "\\xray\HDs\"
out-file -filepath C:\test\acl.csv
Get-ChildItem -Path \\xray\hd -Directory | select PSChildName | Export-Csv C:\test\xray.csv

$csv1= import-csv -path C:\test\xray.csv
foreach ($user in $csv1)
{
$SAM = $user.PSChildName
$account = get-aduser -Identity $SAM -Properties *
$HomeDirectory = "$($newhome)$($Account.SamAccountName)"   
$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $HomeDirectory -Filter *
if ($Acl.AccessToString -like "*everyone*")
{
Write-Output $user.pschildname | out-file -filepath C:\test\acl.csv -Append 
$Ar = New-Object system.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Account.SamAccountName, "modify", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Ar1 = New-Object system.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("yourdomain\Domain Admins", "full", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Ar2 = New-Object system.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("yourdomain\sadmins", "full", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$Acl.setaccessrule($Ar2)
$Acl.setaccessrule($Ar1)
$Acl.Setaccessrule($Ar)
# next line disables inheritance and for my enviroment this is there "everyone" comes from
$Acl.SetAccessRuleProtection($true,$false)
Set-Acl $HomeDirectory $Acl

Write-Host $SAM "fixed user"
} else {Write-Host $SAM "good user"}
}   

#3.0 rename & date acl.csv to record affected folders
  $destpath = 'C:\test\'+"acl_"+(get-date -Format yyyyMMdd)+'.txt'
$sourcepath = 'C:\test\acl.csv'
Move-Item -Path $sourcepath -Destination $destpath

exit
```